# Selenium thinks it has clicked but it hasn't

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My code essentially looks like this:

```
while n < 10:
    'do some stuff'
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    button.click()
    'do some stuff'
```

At same point every time (n=8) Selenium starts to think it has clicked when infact it hasn't.
I have tried send_keys(Keys.ENTER) but hasn't worked. This is very weird because I know button is the same and when i print button.text I get what u want.

Have also tried to check if button is clickable:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='competitions']/ul[1]/li[{}]/h2[1]/span[1]/span[1]".format(N))))
except:
    print('error dude')
```

I don't get any errors.

Comment: How do you know the click isn't working? Or is the problem the click isn't doing the actions you expect?

Comment: element.click() should open the drop-down toggle, like it has done for the previous iterations of my loop, but it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Add some wait /sleep time just above to the click function

Comment: Have you tried IsVisible or IsClickable or inelegant Present options?